# Como identificar qual método chamou a view no Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Como posso identificar qual o `método` que está chamando a `view` dentro dela mesma?

Exemplo:

IndexController.php

```
public function create() {
    return view('index');
}
```

Dentro do arquivo `view/index.blade.php` como faço para retornar o método que chamou, neste exemplo quero retornar `create` ou `create()`.

Comment: Não entendi????

Comment: Editei a publicação exemplificando para uma melhor compreensão

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baste usares `getActionName`

```
echo Route::getCurrentRoute()->getActionName();
```